# How to explain angle hunting to students

Tags: secondary-education, geometry

$I$ is a point of the circle of diameter $JK$. The perpendicular bisector of $JK$ cut the semi-circle not containing $I$ at $M$. Let $N$ and $P$ be the orthogonal projections  of $M$ on $IJ$ and $IP$. Prove that $\angle JMN=\angle PMK$. The next question asks to prove that $JMN$ and $KMP$ are congruent.

[image]

How I did it:

$\angle JMN=90-\angle MJN=90-\left(\angle MJK+\angle KJI\right)=90-(45+\angle KJI)=90-\angle KJI-45=\angle IKJ -45=180-45-\angle MKP -45=90-\angle MKP=\angle PMK$

Maybe there's a shorter way in this case but how can I simplify angle chasing for students?

Comment: Do you mean "How can I ask simpler angle-chasing questions?" or "How can I provide a simpler argument for this particular angle-chasing question?" or, from the title, "How can I simply explain to my students what angle chasing *is*?"

Comment: If you're looking for advice on this particular question (e.g. a simpler way to do it), you're better off asking over at https://math.stackexchange.com/. If your question is about the teaching aspect of questions like this (e.g. how to explain or teach this topic), then would you edit your question to make that a bit clearer?

Comment: @NickC Why math.SE? I'm not asking how to solve it. I'm asking how do experienced teachers handle this type of questions.

Comment: In terms of teaching this material, I would expect that students have been asked to answer simpler versions of this question -- something requiring one or two intermediate steps. Often, students are taught to work forward, seeing what they can directly determine from the given information; and backward, seeing what information they need to know in order to get to their desired result. They are taught to recognize special shapes or situations in a diagram (parallel lines? polygons? vertical angles?) and note what information they give. I have them start with a rough draft to get an answer,

Comment: ...and then go back to write it up as steps in a recipe. I tell them that their target audience should be another student, at the same level, who has not seen this particular problem before, but does recognize the topic-specific terminology. That student should be able to read the work without asking follow-up questions of the author. I have to make this explicit: "Your first draft is probably not sufficient, so plan to write another one." Sometimes, I give them another sheet of paper with the picture on it again, requiring that they rewrite their argument.

Comment: How do you know that OM is a "perpendicular bisector"? Should not you provide either one or another as given, not both?

Comment: Side note: I am amazed by the ability of American educators to invent names for the most mundane and basic things, "angle hunting" or "angle chasing" being one of them. I presume that such a name makes an important task by itself, instead of just tinkering with known information and applying axioms and known theorems. It seems that in American education everything should have a name, everything is bullet-pointed, everything is going according to a plan. Smells like Soviet central planning. Then everyone is surprised why kids cannot solve a problem a little different to one "solved" in class.

Comment: @RustyCore The perpendicular bisector is given in the first line. I'm not an american educator, nor do I teach in English. I just read the term angle hunting/ angle chasing somewhere.

Comment: A meta-comment: the issue raised in this question strikes me as fairly inappropriate or pointless. Namely, the literal question cited is pointlessly extreme for most students... and even for the best students, surely there are better things they could put their attention to. "Angle hunting", forsooth. Let's do real math instead... I'm sorry, I can't take this seriously, even though I did once do well at such (silly) stuff.

Comment: @paulgarrett `the literal question cited is pointlessly extreme for most students`. There's many similar questions in any geometry book whether for school or university students. And why isn't this "real math" for you? It's just logical reasoning.

Comment: @BPP, I agree, there are certainly many equally pointless questions in other textbooks. This make-work tends to teach students that math is silly and pointless, which I'm not happy with... That is, "logical reasoning" in fake situations is (in my opinion) not the highest purpose of mathematics. I realize other people disagree...

Comment: It's pointless to exactly the same degree that physical exercise is "pointless".  Nobody who doesn't work in a sports equipment store will ever be asked to lift a dumbbell in "the real world", so what's the point?  Obviously, it is to train the mind and muscles in an abstract environment so that one is able to lift heavy objects efficiently in the real world.  In the same way, students practice with artificially difficult geometry problems so that they can recognize the same patterns when they are faced with carpentry or orienteering or whatever angle problems face them outside class.

Answer (score 5):

There can be no standard algorithm to solve *angle hunting* problems. You have to build this skill in students by exposing them to simpler problems and gradually increasing the complexity. I suppose the difficulty of these problems can be guaged by the number of properties/constructions required to solve them completely.

The key thing is to begin by working backwards i.e., identify the triangle containing the missing angle. From there keep working your way backwards trying to find the other missing angles or their sums. Some of the properties that could be used in doing this are (not necessarily in the order of difficulty):

- Sum of angles in a triangle is 180
- Sum of supplementary angles is 180
- Sum of complimentary angles is 90
- Vertically opposite angles are equal
- Corresponding angles between parallel lines are equal
- Drop an orthogonal to form a right angled triangle
- Angle subtended by a diameter on a semicircle is 90
- Angle subtended by a chord at centre is twice the angle subtended in the major arc
- Properties of congruent triangles and similar triangles
- ...

The list can't be exhaustive and the properties really depend on the level of students. As I said in the beginning these are open ended problems which can be mastered only through practice. Start with easy and move on to complicated problems.